# Sift Lowe, VLFeat Sift, Python Photogrammetry Toolbox

Tags: python, sift, photogrammetry

I do not have much programming experience, and I am currently working on a project with photogrammetry.

I'm testing out the Python Photogrammetry Toolbox, which allows the user to select Sift Lowe or VLFeat Sift for the feature detection process.

However, the sift.exe crashes whenever the image size is above a certain threshold. My input images are 6000x4000, and I have to scale down to 1500x1000 in order for the program not to crash.

Does anyone know if there is some parameter I can adjust to fix this?

SiftGPU in VisualSFM does not seem to have any programs when I utilize the full resolution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

...for windows version - the problem is in "osm-bundler\osm-bundlerWin64\software\vlfeat\bin\w32\sift.exe" - "sift.exe" files are 32bit (limit of 2GB per process/max image size ~ 1900x1900)

Answer (score 0):

SIFT is now available as part of main opencv repository (as patent on SIFT is expired).

you can check it with the latest version of opencv (as of today 4.4). Try opencv sift using the below code.

```
cv2.SIFT_create()
```

Let us know whether it solves your problem.